# Prove a set is closed

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function and $K$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$. Prove that the set $A = \{x \in \mathbb R : f(x) \in k\}$ is also closed.

Could someone show me direction as I am lost?

Comment: when can you say a set is closed?

Comment: Contains all it's limit points but how do I start off to show it

Comment: you should start with : suppose i have a sequence in A converging to some element.... Then....?

Comment: Are you familiar with the theorem that inverse images (under continuous functions) of closed sets are closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let x(1), x(2),...,x(n) be a sequence of numbers in A = {x: f(x) is in K} which converges to a real number a. Then the sequence f(x(1)), f(x(2)),..., f(x(n)) in K will converge to f(a) because f is continuous in R. Since K is closed, f(a) belongs to K and this implies that a must belong to A. so A is closed.

Comment: Well done i would say :) you could have given some hints instead of writing down each step... any how this is nice :)

Answer (score 3):

Recall a function is continuous if the inverse of open sets is open. This is equivalent to the condition that the inverse of closed sets be closed. The set $\{k\}$ is a closed set, and $A=f^{-1}(\{k\})$, so $A$ is closed as it is the inverse of a closed set.

Comment: Please.. Please give some some for him to think about the hints... Please do not post whole answer at once...

Comment: this is not a straightforward question not for him atleast.. he is just a beginner i guess..

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a continuous function is : A function that inverse image of open (closed) sets are open (closed). 
Thus your set $A=f^{-1}(K)$ is closed.